# Difference between medical and general dermatology

Tags: dermatology, practice-of-medicine

So I am looking at the different clinical interests of dermatologists on the clinic's website.

One provider lists their clinical interests as general dermatology and medical dermatology.

I'm wondering what is the difference between the two subspecialties.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this closed? What details need to be clarified? Where is the private feedback?

Comment: Why is this closed without any feedback? This is a pretty clear question what is the difference between these two subspecialties, I tried looking it up on google, but there is distinction between the two.

Comment: Private feedback isn't provided anywhere on SE. The best I could have done was leave a comment but I felt that the close reason was adequate explanation. All you needed to do was clarify. For example, you say "on the clinic's website" but offer no explanation of what "the clinic" is or even what country it's in. What the close notice asks you to do is edit the question and add more details. Do that and your question can be reopened. Reposting the question is never the right course of action and I'll be deleting the duplicate.